# Xml php attribute nested in data

Tags: php, xml

I am working with the following xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns2:worldmate-parsing-result xmlns:ns2="http://www.worldmate.com/schemas/worldmate-api-v1.xsd" request-id="100793160" received="2014-12-27T16:34:42.000Z">
    <status>SUCCESS</status>
    <error-msg>An itinerary confirmation e-mail was parsed successfully</error-msg>
    <headers>
        <header value="multipart/alternative;  boundary=&quot;Apple-Mail=_62E5BF7A-C482-4FE0-8F43-15613E46D5FD&quot;" name="Content-type" />
        <header value="&lt;xxxxx@me.com&gt;" name="Return-Path" />
        <header value="rule=notspam policy=default score=0 spamscore=0  suspectscore=3 phishscore=0 adultscore=0 bulkscore=0 classifier=spam adjust=0  reason=mlx scancount=1 engine=7.0.1-1412080000 definitions=main-1412270180" name="X-Proofpoint-Spam-Details" />
    </headers>
    <end-user-emails>
        <user email="yyyyy@me.com" />
    </end-user-emails>
    ....
 </ns2:worldmate-parsing-result>
```

I am trying to access the following data within the xml:

```
xxxxx@me.com
yyyyy@me.com
```

I am trying to do access the second email address using the following code.

```
$endus='end-user-emails';
$endUserEmails=$xml->$endus->attributes()->{'user'};
echo $endUserEmails;
```

Not sure why but it is forcing me to use a variable name, and if I use dashes I get errors.

Comment: The problem is that valid XML identifiers are *not* necessarily valid PHP identifiers. If they contain dashes, as you noticed, they are treated as subtractions... and probably syntax errors. In those cases you need the "variable" trick. You can switch to a 100% XML solution using XPath queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `XML DOM Parser` to query the XML:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->Load('file.xml');
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$entries = $xpath->query('//end-user-emails/user/@email');
foreach ($entries as $entry) {
    echo $entry->nodeValue; //Or do something else with the email value
}
```

Crucial is the query:

```
//end-user-emails/user/@email
```

Which means: *"For every tag `<user>` under a tag `<end-user-emails>`, return the `email` attribute."*

For the first email this can be replaced by:

```
//headers/header/@value
```

and then remove the `&lt;` and `&gt`;

**Example:** (with `php -a`)

$ php -a
Interactive mode enabled

```
php > $doc = new DOMDocument();
php > $xmldoc = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
php ' <ns2:worldmate-parsing-result xmlns:ns2="http://www.worldmate.com/schemas/worldmate-api-v1.xsd" request-id="100793160" received="2014-12-27T16:34:42.000Z">
php '     <status>SUCCESS</status>
php '     <error-msg>An itinerary confirmation e-mail was parsed successfully</error-msg>
php '     <headers>
php '         <header value="multipart/alternative;  boundary=&quot;Apple-Mail=_62E5BF7A-C482-4FE0-8F43-15613E46D5FD&quot;" name="Content-type" />
php '         <header value="&lt;xxxxx@me.com&gt;" name="Return-Path" />
php '         <header value="rule=notspam policy=default score=0 spamscore=0  suspectscore=3 phishscore=0 adultscore=0 bulkscore=0 classifier=spam adjust=0  reason=mlx scancount=1 engine=7.0.1-1412080000 definitions=main-1412270180" name="X-Proofpoint-Spam-Details" />
php '     </headers>
php '     <end-user-emails>
php '         <user email="yyyyy@me.com" />
php '     </end-user-emails>
php '  </ns2:worldmate-parsing-result>';
php > $doc->loadXML($xmldoc);
php > $entries = $xpath->query('//end-user-emails/user/@email');
php > foreach ($entries as $entry) {
php { echo $entry->nodeValue."\n";
php { }
yyyyy@me.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Using simple xml (load string or file), you can access the emails with:

```
$a = 'end-user-emails';
$xml = simplexml_load_string($str);

echo ($xml->$a->user->attributes()->email);
```

You need to specify the tag the value is in, and then call the attribute's name